# Assign an External IP to a Node

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running a bare metal Kubernetes cluster and trying to use a Load Balancer to expose my services. I know typically that the Load Balancer is a function of the underlying public cloud, but with recent support for Ingress Controllers it seems like it should now be possible to use nginx as a self-hosted load balancer.

So far, i've been following the example [here](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/complete-example) to set up an nginx Ingress Controller and some test services behind it. However, I am unable to follow Step 6 which displays the external IP for the node that the load balancer is running on as my node does not have an ExternalIP in the addresses section, only a LegacyHostIP and InternalIP.

I've tried manually assigning an ExternalIP to my cluster by specifying it in the service's specification. However, this appears to be mapped as the externalID instead.

How can I manually set my node's ExternalIP address?

Comment: I think I might have figured this out. By binding my Replication Controller to a Service and exposing that, the nginx Load Balancer works. I'm going to leave this question open for now though in case anyone can comment if this is the suggested workaround or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest checking out MetalLB: https://github.com/google/metallb

It allows for externalIP addresses in a baremetal cluster using either ARP or BGP. It has worked great for us and allows you to simply request a LoadBalancer service like you would in the cloud.

Comment: I've marked this as the accepted answer as although it is something extra that needs to be installed upon Kubernetes, it does allow for assignment of an external IP in baremetal environments. Thank you for the tip - very interesting project and think i'll be using it in my next K8S build!

Answer (score 8):

This is something that is tested and works for an nginx service created on a particular node.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: nginx
    namespace: default
spec:
    ports:
    -   port: 80
        protocol: TCP
        targetPort: 80
        name: http
    -   port: 443
        protocol: TCP
        targetPort: 443
        name: https
    externalIPs:
      - '{{external_ip}}'
    selector:
        app: nginx
```

Assumes an nginx deployment upstream listening on port 80, 443.
The externalIP is the public IP of the node.

Comment: Could you explain where the template value for external_ip is sourced from? This is the almost the exact service definition that I ended up creating for my nginx Ingress RC but I have hardcoded the external IP.

Comment: If I'm setting up a node on DigitalOcean then it's the node's public IP that I put in there. So when I provision a system, I get the externalIP, then I compile the nginx template and then run create-service.

Comment: After a little more digging, i've found that the External and Internal IPs are determined by the specific cloud that Kubernetes is running on. Support varies from cloud to cloud, [https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/cloudprovider/providers/gce/gce.go](here's the one for Google Compute Engine) for example (search for ExternalIP to see where it is sourcing that data from). Since it's dependent on the individual cloud provider, it would seem that support is highly variable.

Comment: @KingJ I am also trying the same blog but no luck, I am also not getting the external IP. I am running the Kubernetes cluster in a private data center. If you find any solution to this can you please share ?

Comment: @VaibhavJain External IPs are only assigned on certain cloud providers. If you're running this on your own infrastructure (e.g. private datacentre as you say) you won't get an external IP.

Comment: @KingJ Thanks! Is there a way I can load balance to my pods running same containers by using service ? and get the IP so that I can test from the external browser? I tried nodePort type it exposes the node port but I am not able ti use them from the service it self. Any help will be appreciated :D

Comment: @VaibhavJain You might want to look at setting up a [Kubernetes Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/). This acts as a reverse proxy through to your services - both for HTTP(S) traffic and also regular TCP traffic. The Ingress controller runs on a node and forwards the traffic through to the appropriate service/pod. ([Sample configs](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress)).

Comment: @KingJ Thanks for you suggestion, Just wanted to confirm Do I need a public routeable IP on all the nodes or just on the Master? as when I create a service and hit the cluster IP of the service along with the exposed Nodeport I am not able to access the application. But I can see that kube-proxy is listening on that port.